# How do you replace the inverted commas for the following output and insert commas between the values as shown below using python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am using the following code below

```
y = bin(25)[2:]
y = [y]
tuple(y)
print y
```

The output here is ['11001'] and I am looking for the output [1,1,0,0,1] using regular expression so as to automate the plotting a square wave for the generated binary values from decimal numbers.Could any help me out.

Comment: Inverted commas are called quotes.

Comment: By *"replace the inverted commas"* do you actually mean *"convert from strings to integers"*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin):

> Convert an integer number to a binary string. The result is a valid Python expression. If x is not a Python int object, it has to define an **index**() method that returns an integer.

i.e. `y` is a string.

If you want to convert it to an array of integers, you need to actualyl do that conversion yourself:

```
y = bin(25)[2:]
y = [int(yi) for yi in y]
print y # [1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need regex for such problems you can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to map the `int` function on each element in your list :

```
>>> y = bin(25)[2:]
>>> y
'11001'
>>> map(int,y)
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

or just use a list comprehension :

```
>>> [int(i) for i in y]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: There's not need for the `list(y)`; just use `y`, strings are iterable.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yep, a foolish mistake ;) i just used the OP's code! thanks for reminding.